# Alpine Linux - "Secrets were required, but not provided" when connecting to a wifi connection, but works when connecting to another

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, alpine-linux

I am using Alpine Linux to connect to my wifi home network. I have two main wifi access points, let's call them WORKING and NOT_WORKING. When I connect to WORKING through `nmcli`, the connection is instant and works perfectly. However, when I try connecting to the NOT_WORKING network I get the following error:

```
$ sudo nmcli dev wifi con NOT_WORKING password not_working_pass
Error: Connection activation failed: (7) Secrets were required, but not provided.
```

The reason I prefer to connect to the NOT_WORKING connection instead of using the other one is because the signal is much stronger in the NOT_WORKING connection.

I tried deleting any previous connection with the following command, in case there would be any conflict:

```
$ sudo nmcli con delete NOT_WORKING
```

But that still doesn't work.

I also tried managing the connection with `nmtui`, but same problem persists.

Since I can connect to the WORKING network successfully, it seems like there is something about the configuration of the router that maybe the system doesn't like, although I'm not sure what could it be, since all of the configuration seems to be the same. Or maybe I'm missing something, I'm not sure honestly.

Any help?

Comment: Try the solutions in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420640/unable-to-connect-to-any-wifi-with-networkmanager-due-to-error-secrets-were-req).

Comment: @harrymc I tried all of them but none of them helped unfortunately

Comment: That post also had [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395059/how-to-stop-mac-address-from-changing-after-disconnecting). Did you try it too?

Comment: @harrymc yes I tried that too, but didn't work